# Website which can make a call to a given phone number

Tags: ios, phone-number

Is there any website/server through which I can do a tie-up for doing following:

1. I will pass my user Id and a phone number.
2. Using my user Id, it will know who I am and what is my phone number.

3.1 It will make a call to the phone number which I have passed and to me and get both of us connected?
3.2 It will make a call to the phone number which I have passed and it should display my number in his mobile.

Please let me know whether any of these 3.1 or 3.2 is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly that you're looking for, but have a look at the [Ribbit API](http://developer.ribbit.com/).